# Passed data returns null flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page `home_page` which uses the `BottomNavigationBar` For the body i use `screens` property which contains all the pages based on the current index. I also have a method which i modified for the sake of the question and that passes the number 4000 to the data property. I then want to pass the number 4000 inside data property to the different screens

```
/*home_page.dart*/

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }
  static int? data;
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [
    Child1Page(
      passedData: data
    ),
Child2Page(
      passedData: data,
    ),
Child3Page(
      passedData: data,
    ),
Child4Page(
      passedData: data,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        
        onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            label: 'child1',
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_to_home_screen),
            label: 'child2',
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_to_home_screen),
            label: 'child3',
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_to_home_screen),
            label: 'child4',
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
   
    data = 4000;
  }

  
}
```

```
/*child1page.dart*/

class Child1Page extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic passedData;
  const Child1Page({Key? key, this.passedData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Child1PageState createState() => _Child1PageState();
}

class _Child1PageState extends State<Child1Page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.passedData),
    );
  }
}
```

The screens where you can navigate are also in seperate files, one of them for the sake of the question i called `child1_page`. I am passing the `data` from the `home_page` in to `child1_page` via the screens property. But the problem is that the property `passedData` is null when i want to acces it in `child1_page`. For some reason `passedData` is not invoked with the data inside property `data` i pass from the method `getData` and so passedData returns null. My question is how can i pass the data from the method `getData` to the property `data` and pass it to the property `screens`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from the fact that at the time you create the widgets, the data is null. To fix this, you could make the list a getter value:

```
List<Widget> get screens => [
    Child1Page(
      passedData: data
    ),
Child2Page(
      passedData: data,
    ),
Child3Page(
      passedData: data,
    ),
Child4Page(
      passedData: data,
    ),
  ];
```

a getter value get's computed every time you call it, it works similar to a function with no parameters, it means that every time you try to read from `screens`, Child1Page will be redefined with the current value of data. Hopefully it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is coming because of `getData()`, It is future method, you need to `await` to fetch data. You can  use `FutureBuilder` to handle this case but calling `setState` inside `FutureBuilder` will recall the API again.

While `items` are `const` on `bottomNavigationBar` we can create empty screen list check empty while using on body.

```dart
class _AppXState extends State<AppX> {
  static int? data;
  List<Widget> screens = [];
  int currentIndex = 0;

  Future<void> getData() async {
    data = 400; // you may not even using data
    setState(() {
      screens.add(Child1Page(passedData: data));
      //.....
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: screens.isEmpty
          ? const CircularProgressIndicator() //handling watting
          : screens[currentIndex],
```